# Implement backup strategy in cloud with a slow connection (around 150 GB)

Tags: windows, backup, raid

I want to implement a backup strategy based in cloud to prevent data lost by disasters.

Scenario:

```
Proliant Server ML350
1X136GB (Windows 2008 installation and applications)
1x136GB (Applications and files -excel, docx, ...)

(Each logic partition has got RAID 1 configuration with SAS disks)
```

The main problem is that connection to Internet is really slow, always lower than 0,5 Mbps and even lower on the work time.

The company has got a cloud storage service with 500 GBs.

I am wonder which is a good strategy to get a copy of all the data in the cloud.

The first approach is upload a full backup and then to do differential copies each day. But I don't know it is a good practice to keep hundred of differential copies.

The media to store the backups could be a 1TB external disk connected to the server by USB for example.

For the software I see cobian back (it's free) or backupchain (cheap). I don't know if it's possible to do the backup of a compressed image of whole the system.

Comment: At those speeds you'd never get the initial backup done; the first differential would run next February, if you're lucky. If you had a disaster, you'd also need weeks to get the data back. I'd be more inclined to go for a NAS with removable drives & take them off-site in rotation.

Comment: There is a NAS that can move to another room in order to get more security against disaster. Thus, I can upload the backup of application databases and other data files to the cloud using the cloud service. Backing to the NAS, I am wonder which is appropiate method to backup the system (Windows 2008).

Comment: You still need an off-site copy in case the building burns down. I've always used Acronis for the Windows machines, which now has an off-site option [though I've not used it myself]

Comment: There are cloud backup services which offer to send you a HDD in order for you to restore your data.  I am sure there are cloud services that exist that will allow you to send them HDDs in order to populate the initial backup.